# My restricted PHP page isn't restricting access bases on if a user is logged in

Tags: php, mysql

With the help of this site I have a log in script that now works. The problem is the page I am trying to restrict is not restricting access, When I go to the page without logging in it still gives me access to the page. I am quite new to PHP so your help and comments are greatly appreciated.

The code for the page is

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/PropSuite.php'); ?>
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}


session_start();
//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: http://localhost/PropSuite/index.php');
    die();
}



?>
```

And the code for the log in script is.

```
<?php



function validateUser()
{

    session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
}


?>

<?php

ob_start(); // Start output buffering

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

session_start(); //must call session_start before using any $_SESSION variables
$username = isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:'';
     $password = isset($_POST['password'])?$_POST['password']:'';
//connect to the database here

$hostname_PropSuite = "localhost";
$database_PropSuite = "propsuite";
$username_PropSuite = "root";
$password_PropSuite = "root";
$PropSuite = mysql_pconnect($hostname_PropSuite, $username_PropSuite, $password_PropSuite) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db($database_PropSuite, $PropSuite);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$query = "SELECT password, salt FROM admin_users WHERE username = '$username';";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such user exists
{
    header('Location: http://localhost/PropSuite/index.php?login=fail');

    die();
}
$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );
if($hash != $userData['password']) //incorrect password
{
    header('Location: http://localhost/PropSuite/index.php?login=fail');

    die();
}
else
{
   validateUser(); //sets the session data for this user
}
//redirect to another page or display "login success" message
header('Location: http://localhost/PropSuite/main');
die()




//redirect to another page or display "login success" message


?>
```

Again, Thank you in advance for your help and for the mods, I apologise if I am posting similar questions.

Comment: make a separate script, with only 
`session_start();    print_r($_SESSION);`

with that you can see whats actually inside of `$_SESSION`

Comment: Thanks for that, this comes up with Array ( [foo] => bar [valid] => 1 [userid] => ) any ideas?

Comment: Use `mysql_num_rows($result) != 1` to ensure that it is only one user with that username you are talking about.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev Many thanks for that, where would I place this in my code? thanks again

Comment: Replace this code - `if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such user exists` with `if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) //no such user exists
`

Comment: Also at the very bottom of your log in script, add a semi-colon(;) after die(). `die()'` .

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, is this right:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
    return true;
```

are there no brackets missing?

I would write it like this:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['valid']) && !empty($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'] === true) {
        return true;
 }
```

Perhaps this is the point. If this was wrong, your login will everytime be true. And then you can see the content, even if there is not a Session!

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score -1):

return true, 
return false

if session
display page

else display Please log in to view this page or somethign

Comment: Please be more descriptive with your answers. And check spelling / grammar.